# How path should be configured for a python project?

Tags: python, import, importerror

After exhaustive research on this topic the past few days, I still don't understand what is the **proper** way to handle *python path* for a specific project. I describe below the situation that I am in and the exact question I have about it.

### Problem statement

I have downloaded a project that I want to work on from GitHub. An *abstract* structure of the project is represented below, having removed unnecessary components:

```
project
|-- experiments
|   |-- cnn_experiments
|       |-- __init__.py
|       |-- train.py
|       |-- datasets
|           |-- __init__.py
|           |-- module_A.py
|-- src
    |-- cnn
        |-- io
            |-- __init__.py
            |-- module_B.py
```

*Note: from the structure above are missing only some directories under **cnn** directory with some extra functionalities. Except for this, the structure is the same as I downloaded it from GitHub.*

In `train.py` there is the following `import` statement:

```
from cnn_experiments.datasets.module_A import Class_A
```

From **inside cnn_experiments** directory I run `python train.py` command and I get this error:

> ImportError: No module named cnn_experiments.datasets.module_A

Similarly, I get the corresponding error when I run `module_A.py` that has the `import` statement:

```
from cnn.io.module_B import Class_B
```

Especially for the second case, that the path is completely different, when I use `print(sys.path)` from inside `train.py` I can tell that Python can't resolve where my `import` refers to, but the problem is why.

### Question

- In this case, that the project is *small*, how can I have full access to import all the directories? I came across with some answers which refer to changing PYTHONPATH in .bashrc file. But it doesn't make sense to me configuring .bashrc *exporting* to it the path for every project.
- Since I understand that having full access from every module to every other module in a project is not generally desired for the sake of *abstractness* and *independence*, how can I set up the path so that the modules to be imported are visible?

*Thanks in advance for any help!*

---

*EDIT:* I forgot to mention that I use *Python 2.7* on *Ubuntu 18.04 LTS*.

Comment: The "proper" way how one should handle such things is for the project to be installable, e.g. via ``setup.py`` or ``pyproject.toml``. Everything else is a workaround.

Comment: Ok. So a `setup.py` file is needed to build automatically all dependencies, right? But now, since for example this project I work on doesn't come with a `setup.py` file, is there a _trick_ to have access to all directories?

Comment: Not if you are simultaneously asking for the proper way, without PYTHONPATH, and without ``setup.py``.

Comment: I am interested in two things: 1) I want to know what is the _proper_ way to handle a python project so that it can be used _easily_ by others, etc (which you already answered to me) and 2) if there is a trick for now since the project is not mine and I just want to _investigate_ how it works.