# How to import modules from parent directory/different package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror

Working on a project that I cloned from GitHub, I came across the problem that `import` statements about modules in **parent** directories or **different packages** weren't recognized throwing `ImportError`. I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65014153/how-path-should-be-configured-for-a-python-project) question about my specific occasion and continued researching about it.

Finally, I've come to a *conclusion* that I would like to share along with some resources for similar *future* problems.

---

### Question

- How to `import` a module from a **parent** directory or from a **different package**?
- What is the *proper* way to do it?

Comment: Python is built to work with _installed_ modules and packages. When you install a package, its scripts go into a directory on the system `PATH` for execution and its packages and modules go into one of the module paths maintained by python. If you want to reach into a different package cloned from github, ..., don't. Instead, _install_ that package and now its just an import away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer

*(or just some information about the question)*

According to [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path), importing a module works like this:

> When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter ***first** searches for a built-in* module with that name. If not found, it then searches for a file named spam.py in a list of directories given by the variable sys.path. sys.path is initialized from these locations:
>
> - The directory containing the input script (or the current directory when no file is specified).
> - PYTHONPATH (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable PATH).
> - The installation-dependent default.

So, in the case that you simply want to `import` a module, e.g. `my_pkg.my_module.py`, which resides in a **different** location than the module *importing* it, `my_pkg` **should be in the list that** `sys.path` **returns**. For this to happen, there are *(as far as I know)* three ways:

1. Modify `PYTHONPATH` variable. (as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3402176/9707473)) *- **Not** preferred*
2. Modify `sys.path` at *runtime*. (as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16114586/9707473)) *- **Not** preferred*
3. Having a `setup.py` file that resolves the import dependencies of your modules *(and doing many other important things, too)*. *- **Proper** way*

So, the first 2 ways above are generally considered *not* to be a *good practice*, but rather a *temporary - bad* solution that will lead to further problems during development process. The third one, though, is the *best* way to build a *distributable*, *well-organized* project that will be easily used by other people. Some of the benefits of `setup.py` file are illustrated [here](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html) along with whole functionality of it.

With a `setup.py` file you can clearly *configure* which are the packages that contain the modules to be *imported* to solve `ImportError` and do many other useful things about your project.

Below are cited two very *illustrative* tutorials about **how to use** import statements and **how to create** a `setup.py` file, that I *strongly recommend* to take a look at:

- https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html
- https://www.pythonforthelab.com/blog/how-create-setup-file-your-project/

---

*EDIT:* Also, you can find plenty of information about how to *configure, package and distribute* your project here:

- https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/

Personally, I find it very useful in order to build a pretty good first `setup.py` file.